# When to use arrays to define commands?

Tags: variable, array

I read somewhere that arrays are best for making commands.

```
sent='A long sentence with lots of words in it.'
long=('-e' '/ long/d')
lots=('-e' '/ lots of/d')
init=('-e' '/ in it/d')
echo sent | sed -r ${long[@]} ${lots[@]} ${init[@]}
```

I had some problem with a non-array variable, so I've been using arrays like this. Is this necessary? When would an array be superfluous, and when would it be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary if your arguments have spaces in them. However, you aren't using them correctly. You need to quote the expansions.

```
echo sent | sed -r "${long[@]}" "${lots[@]}" "${init[@]}"
```

Comment: Is the quoting necessary if the content doesn't need to be quoted? In this case, I would normally type the command without quoting the -e with the command.

Can I quote the whole content of each array, like long=('-e / long/d')?

Comment: No, because `-e` and `/ long/d` need to be presented as two distinct arguments to `sed`. Failing to quote the expansion causes `sed` to see `-e`, `/` and `long/d` as three separate arguments.

Comment: The number of cases where quoting is actually *incorrect* is so small that you should always quote parameter expansions unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Does sed see the quotes around -e and / long/d, or is it some other mechanism? I wonder if double quoting is different, if there's problems with subquoting, etc.

Comment: No; `long=(-e "/ long/d"); sed -r "${long[@]}"` is the same as `sed -r -e "/ long/d"`. It's a matter of how the shell expands various parameters, independent of `sed`. You might want to check out http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays.